# Append folder name and increment by 1 using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am a little green to this part of batch scripting, but what I am trying to do is a append a bunch of folder names and increment by 1 whilst respecting the time stamp i.e newest folder first, oldest folder last.

I have looked at other scripts with no avail.

Before

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
Folder 4
Folder 5
Folder 6
```

After

```
Folder 1 - Part 001          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:55:20
Folder 4 - Part 002          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:55:24
Folder 3 - Part 003          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:56:28
Folder 6 - Part 004          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:58:24
Folder 5 - Part 005          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:59:20
Folder 43 - Part 006          - Time stamp 1/1/2014 - 18:59:59
```

Extra function

Is there a way to do all the above but skip all folders that contain `- GROUP VIDEO` at the end of it. (I am not sure if I should create a new post or not?)

Comment: can you show us the code you already have ?

Comment: Do your folders sort by name correctly, or are your examples nothing like the real thing?

Comment: @etr - I do not not have any code as such as I could not find anything that would work remotely to what I wanted.

Comment: @foxidrive The folder will be of different names however the time stamp will be correct, updated post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ^|find /i /v "GROUP VIDEO" ') do (
set /a num+=1
set name=000!num!
set name=!name:~-3!
ren "%%a" "%%a - Part !name!"
)
pause
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Testing now. Thank you

Comment: If I wanted specify the folder location where to do the operations, would it be `cd\` then `cd c:\test\test`. Tried it but no joy. Thanks

Comment: After line 3 add `cd /d "c:\test\test"`

Comment: Is there a way to get the above code to skip any folder  containing the phrase `GROUP VIDEO`. Thank you, PS. If you want me to create a new thread please let me know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would this be correct `('dir /b /ad /o-d ^|find /i /v "GROUP VIDEO" ^|find /i /v "GROUP AUDIO" ')` To have multiple expressions?

Comment: Yes.  You could use just one expression too in your case to filter them both on one pass.  This would be faster but for a small number of folders you couldn't tell.  `^|find /i /v " - GROUP"`  NOTE too that the `- GROUP` is case insensitive with the `/i` switch.

Comment: Ok, so this would be correct? `('dir /b /ad /o-d ^|find /i /v "GROUP VIDEO" ^|find /i /v "SERVER STATS" ')`