# Skip if any folder contains "Part" anywhere

Tags: batch-file

I have this script thanks to foxidrive [Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786352/append-folder-name-and-increment-by-1-using-batch-script/24786579?noredirect=1#comment38480850_24786579)

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
cd /d "C:\testfolder\test\test"  

if /i "%a:~-7%"=="Part" goto:process else goto:next

:process
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ') do (
set /a num+=1
set name=000!num!
set name=!name:~-3!
ren "%%a" "%%a - Part !name!"
)
pause

:next
pause
```

Before

```
Folder 1
```

After

```
Folder 1 - Part 001
```

If I execute the script again

```
Folder 1 - Part 001 - Part 001
```

Solution

```
if /i "%a:~-7%"=="Part" goto:process else goto:next
```

I would like the above code to look for the workd "Part". If it is found anywhere, it would `GOTO:NEXT`. I am not sure what I am missing here as I have tried it with not avail and I have looked around for some time now. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: In the script you've posted, you appear to be testing the value of `%a` before you've set it. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @icabod Yes you are right, but I am green to this to be honest. So it would be? `if /i ":~-7%"=="Part" goto:process else goto:next"` ? Thanks

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer (as I'm about to head home for the day), but no - you would need to check for `%a` containing `Part`, perhaps by searching it for a [substring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7005951/218597).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small batch file demonstrates how to identify subdirectories with string *Part* anywhere within directory name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\testfolder\test\test"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ') do (
   set "DirName=%%a"
   if "!DirName:Part=!" == "!DirName!" (
      echo Directory "%%a" does not contain string "Part".
   ) else (
      echo Directory "%%a" contains string "Part".
   )
)
endlocal
echo.
pause
```

`!DirName:Part=!` creates a string from value of environment variable **DirName** where the string *Part* is replaced by an empty string. This string is compared with unmodified value of environment variable **DirName**. If both strings are identical, the directory name does not contain *Part*.

Replace the 2 `echo` commands with whatever you need for your task.

This second example code searches in directory `C:\testfolder\test\test` for any subdirectory containing the string *Part* in directory name in order from newest to oldest directory. The loop is exit immediately on first subdirectory with *Part* in name found. The environment variable **DirName** contains in this case the name of this subdirectory.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\testfolder\test\test"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ') do (
   set "DirName=%%a"
   if not "!DirName:Part=!" == "!DirName!" goto PartDirFound
)

DirName=
endlocal
echo No subdirectory contains "Part" in name.
echo.
pause
rem Exit this batch file as nothing do.
goto :EOF

:PartDirFound
rem Insert your code here instead of commands echo and pause.
echo "!DirName!" contains the string "Part" in name.
echo.
pause
DirName=
endlocal
```

But match faster would be following batch with same execution behavior:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\testfolder\test\test"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad /o-d ') do (
   set "DirName=%%a"
   goto PartDirFound
)

cls
echo No subdirectory contains "Part" in name.
echo.
pause
rem Exit this batch file as nothing do.
goto :EOF

:PartDirFound
rem Insert your code here instead of commands echo and pause.
echo "%DirName%" contains the string "Part" in name.
echo.
pause
DirName=
```

Comment: OK but from what I understand this is a loop right. So even if the last folder was named with `PART` inside it. It would not go out of the loop until it go to the folder. `@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\testfolder\test\test"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ') do (
   set "DirName=%%a"
   if "!DirName:Part=!" == "!DirName!" (
      GOTO:PROCESS
   ) else (
      GOTO:NEXT
   )
)
pause



:NEXT
echo next
pause

:PROCESS
echo PROCESS
pause
`

Comment: I would like all the folders to be checked to see if they contain the word `PART` If any folder contains the word `PART` `GOTO:NEXT` If all the folders does not contain the word `PART` `GOTO:PROCESS`. So all the folder would have to be checked in advanced before any `GOTO` can be executed, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The solution thanks to Mofi

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0

cd /d "C:\test\test"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad /o-d ') do (
   set "DirName=%%a"
   goto PartDirFound
)

cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d ') do (
set /a num+=1
set name=000!num!
set name=!name:~-3!
ren "%%a" "%%a - Part !name!"
)
pause
rem Exit this batch file as nothing do.
goto :EOF

:PartDirFound
rem Insert your code here instead of commands echo and pause.
echo "%DirName%" contains the string "Part" in name.
echo.
pause
DirName=
```